# MonoTouch - Setting Bundle - iPhone

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, bundle

I am trying to create a app preference so that users can store prefs.

In XCode I would click the "Settings Bundle" under New File.

How do I do this in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Craig Dunn has a detailed post on using a [MonoTouch Settings.bundle](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/08/monotouch-settingsbundle.html).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used MonoTouch, but a settings bundle is just a folder with a bunch of settings plists (and localizations) — no compilation involved. So just create the setting bundles in Xcode or other means, then drag that bundle into your MonoTouch app.